# I want to execute a specific folder within a Collection only during the first iteration of the run. Is this possible?

Tags: postman, newman

I have a collection which I would like to run iterative (data-driven) tests against, but I have an auth folder which I only want to run during the first iteration of the collection run.

Is this possible?

I know I could separate the folder out into its own Collection, and store the variable - but, I am not sure if this will behave properly in my CI testing pipeline. Hoping for a solution specific to my question.

.

---

.

**EDIT**: I was able to come up with a solution that nearly solves my problem.

In the pre-request script of the first request in the folder I want to skip, I added:

```
if (typeof(varSetInItrZero) === "string") {
    postman.setNextRequest("theRequestIWant");
}
```

Only outstanding issue, is that it continues to send the current request anyway. Any way to tell Postman to skip the current request in a given pre-request script?

Answer (score -1):

Final answer:

I (finally) tried to configure this purely via command-line (using three separate collections). This effort was successful.

My solution..

```
call newman run setup.json -e environment.json -g globals.json --export-environment environment.json -r cli

call newman run collection.json -e environment.json -g globals.json --export-environment environment.json -r cli,htmlextra

call newman run teardown.json -e environment.json -g globals.json --export-environment environment.json -r cli

exit
```

Comment: That actually looks good as you're not the only one that also need to do this.  Using mochajs, and use newman as a library, now I can have one test runs the login "collection" and then 2nd test to call an iterative loops to test a set of endpoints driven by data, then another test to run the "collection" to logout.    Now my next problem is wether I can use cookie.jar to save the session id.

Comment: This [resource](https://medium.com/apis-with-valentine/postman-how-to-write-files-to-disk-5ee398624a42) is going to be your best friend.

Comment: Essentially, you'll want to run newman as an npm module by saving a js file to your working directory, containing something like this:

`
const newman = require('newman'),
      fs = require('fs');

newman.run({
    collection: require('./postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('beforeRequest', function (error, args) {
    if (error)
        console.error(error);
    else
        fs.writeFile(`request.txt`, args.request.body.raw, function (error) {
            if (error)
                console.error(error);
        });    
    }
})...had to truncate this
`

Comment: `
.on('request', function (error, args) {
    if (error)
        console.error(error);
    else {
        fs.writeFile(`response.txt`, args.response.stream, function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });        
    }
});
`

Comment: Now, obviously you're not looking to output the request body in your scenario.. But, the basic idea is there and you can bend it to your will.